# browser not interpreting html template

Tags: html, go

I have one function in a very small Go application that does a query to a database, retrieves some data and inserts it in the template (main.html). the data is getting inserted into the template (see image), however the html is not being interpreted by the browser (Chrome and Firefox)[image]. My browsers are otherwise working fine.  Is there something that I'm not doing correct with the template?

```
func Root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    t := template.Must(template.New("main").ParseFiles("main.html"))
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT title, author, description FROM books")
    PanicIf(err)
    defer rows.Close()

    books := []Book{}

    for rows.Next() {
        b := Book{}
        err := rows.Scan(&b.Title, &b.Author, &b.Description)
        PanicIf(err)
        books = append(books, b)
    }
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main.html", books)

}
```

main.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>


  <body>

    <div class="container">
     <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
{{ range . }}
  <tr>
    <td>{{.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{.Author}}</td>
    <td>{{.Description}}</td>
  </tr>
{{ end }}
</table>
    </div>
  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: "A young hipster bear seeks his fortune in the wild city of Irvine" I'd read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content type, although it's rather weird it didn't automatically set it for you.

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main.html", books)
```

//edit

Also for correctness sake, you should add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your template, not related to the problem though.

Comment: thanks, setting content type was the problem. It does seem weird to me because I have created a few Go files before and never had to set content type before

Comment: That's rather weird, usually Go will automatically detect that. oh well, glad t help.

Comment: @TomokoYamaguchi - Go should check the output through `http.DetectContentType` on the first write if there's no header already set. Is that your *exact* template file and handler?

Comment: The issue is the lack of a DOCTYPE. Someone had the same issue last week. Setting the Content-Type header is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are doing `import "text/template"` and should be doing `import "html/template"`, but the other answer will also fix it for you.

Comment: while setting content-type fixes it, you nearly always be using "html/template" when serving html!

Comment: I was importing html/template, setting the content type fixed it